# how to display a link on a node view page?

Tags: nodes

I want to display a link on a node view page just like the "Add new comment" link.
How should I do this?

I think it can be done through `hook_node_view()`,  but how can I use this hook?

Comment: What do you mean "how can I use this hook"? You use this hook just like you use any other hook that your module implements: by implementing an appropriately named function and waiting for Drupal to call it.

Comment: I have use the hook but nothing happens. Can you write code so that I match it with my code?

Comment: First of all, check whether your implementation of the hook is actually executed, e.g by calling [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message) inside your hook implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation of [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), add an element to the `$node->content` array. The element should be a renderable array as expected by [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7).

Comment: Can you provide me some code help?

Comment: Sure; you provide the code and I help by telling you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem using hook_node_view.

Answer (score 1):

In drupal6, you could implement the [hook_links](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_link/6) (just like the node module does http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_link/6)

Comment: But I am using drupal 7. How could I do this in drupal 7?

Comment: have a look at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_build_content/7

Answer (score 0):

Use `hook_node_view` and add new variable `$node->my_link` , add template file page--my_node.tpl.php and place that link wherever you want. This is solution for dynamic link for every node.

If you just want to add some no-dynamic link to your node_type than just add it in template file.